# for each - NullReferenceException

Tags: loops, for-loop, null, each, nullreferenceexception

```
 Public containerInfoParam As Specialized.NameValueCollection

 offlineContainerID = offlineContainerID.ToString.Substring(4)
 Dim offlineContainerIDArray As Array =  offlineContainerID.ToString.Split(";")

 For Each i As String In offlineContainerIDArray
    containerInfoParam.Add("id", i)
 Next
```

This is how I'm trying to add a Parameter for every entry in the array as I don't know how many entrys it will have. Everytime I try it gives me a NullReferenceException. What am I doing wrong?
The parameter is a Specialized.NameValueCollection

EDIT: Thats how the array is initialized and filled with entries. offlineContainerID is filled with 30 digit ID's starting with a "1 - " (Thats why the Substring(4) and the ID's are seperated by a semicolon(;).
I know its probably not the best was to implement this, still learning :)

Comment: How is the array initialized? Please upload more code and we can help.

Comment: If they don't contain semicolons and you're splitting on semicolons, my guess is you won't get any data. Split on "-" or "1 -" or whatever punctuation is used.

Comment: splitting the ID's is working and filling the array is as well. just adding it as a parameter gives me the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public containerInfoParam As New Specialized.NameValueCollection

It took me a while to see that new was missing. In general, try exception handling.